# Target all tumblr posts in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css

I'm trying to get a circle appear right in the middle of each tumblr (image) post and have the following code to find it (excuse my horrible jquery):

```
    var imageheight = $('article').height();
        imageheight /= 2;
        imageheight -= 50;
    var imagewidth = $('article').width();
        imagewidth /= 2;
        imagewidth -= 50;
    $(".circle").css('top', imageheight);
    $(".circle").css('left', imagewidth);
```

This works, but only for the first image.. I need this to apply to all of the blog's posts and not only the first one. All the different post blocks are in an article tag..

Thanks

Comment: can you show us your html, or the page you are trying to apply this to?

Comment: @SamBattat The page im editing is http://nichotest2.tumblr.com. This is the HTML, CSS & jQuery: http://pastebin.com/4XUPsbgh

Answer (score 0):

I think your code is probably working as expected. Try setting your article element to `position:relative;`. Absolute positioned child elements will be positioned in reference to the body if you don't set the parent to relative.

Here is a quick fiddle to show an example. Try removing the `position:relative;` on the article element and you will see that both of the child elements will be sitting on top of each other, which would make it appear to only be working on the first article.

http://jsfiddle.net/y4r7wgrg/1/

See [this page](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp) for more information on CSS positioning.